# Can you Program/Test CUDA in a Virtual Machine?

Tags: cuda, virtual-machine, gpu

I ask this as a programming and environment question. Can you test/program CUDA within a virtual machine accessing the physical GPU card?

I am buying a new (really nice system) to, in part, experiment with basic CUDA programming. The processor will be an Intel i7-4770 which supports VT-d (direct IO pass-through) OR a i7-4770K which does not. Will the VT-d support allow access to the GPU card from the VMs? (I have looked at Intel, motherboard mfg. sites, and docs on VMs but did not see an answer to this question.)

I plan to run Linux as my base operating system on the new development box with virtual machines (probably via QEMU/KVM) to test the software in other environments such as Windows and Mac OS. I other words, I would do the major development on the Linux box and then need to test on a virtual machine running on the same box.

But, will the VM OSs be able to access the GPU card for testing/development?

[First asked July 2013]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what NVIDIA card you're using. See for example: (this is in regards to Xen)
http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenVGAPassthroughTestedAdapters#Nvidia_display_adapters

The short answer is you probably would need to rely on modifying a consumer card as they link above as 'Australian crazy guy'.

Comment: Thank you.I have been working on this with KVM (QEMU). I have not been able to get the pass-through to work using KVM. One issue might be motherboard support under KVM. The VT-d support requires a fairly complex combination of support: CPU, motherboard, BIOS, and virtualization environment. KVM appears to require a dedicated IRQ to the pass-through resource (CUDA card). I continue to work on it to see if I can get pass-through to work. Thank you for the helpful links.

Comment: Hi both. Any news on this? I too would like to get CUDA set up on a QEMU machine.